# What is the duration of changing engine oil in Bikes and What is the impact of oil in Bike mileage?

Tags: engine, motorcycle, oil-change

I am asking two question which has some connection closely.

I having Honda Shine Bike which is running fine. I am curious about changing oil...Is it necessary to change engine oil in every 4 months or when we submit the bike for servicing.

And If I change the engine oil 3 times in a year then its impact good on my bikes' mileage??

Any Suggestion please...

Comment: All servicing according to the manufacturer's specifications is good for mileage.

Comment: As Mike said, because every manufacturer's recommendations are going to be different.

Answer (score -1):

Duration of changing Engine Oil in Bikes:

Will split this into two cases.

Case 1: A Normal Rider (Riding minimum distance to within 60 - 100 Kms per
Day)

Case 2: A Long Rider (Riding more than 300 Kms per Day)

For Case 1: Person needs to change it after certain kms say 2500 - 3000 kms.

For Case 2: Person needs to ensure the property of the oil remains good and if in case, it low as engine eats a very small amount of oil over greater distance. If so, can top up and retain the oil level in the bikes.

However checking oil levels in the bikes is mandate after 2000 kms. for both the cases, thereby ensuring its in good condition and not in pitch black color if so, engine oil has to be changed.

Engine Oil's impact over mileage:

If the engine oil quality and condition is good and it will promote the mileage of the vehicle to a greater impact.

On the other hand, over a period of time, as the engine oil gets polluted (by its operation of circulating to all parts of the engine), contaminated by the pollutants (minuscule) particles obtained via wear and tear of the engine during its operation (i.e. on riding).

As far as mileage is concerned. Always ride your vehicle (Bike) on its top gear, as far as the gear ratio of the vehicle is concerned, it fetches you the best mileage. Since the gear ratio will be 1:1. By this, the highest mileage of the vehicle is achieved.

In addition to that, engine oil flush to be done after every 50,000 kms in a vehicle to ensure the engine health is good and clean. Note: It varies from one to other depend upon the health condition of engine is concerned.

Adding the engine oil additive to the engine oil also, aids the engine oil for better and smooth performance of the engine thereby enhancing the better mileage of your vehicle to a greater extent.

That's why all the vehicles gives the better mileage on highways than driving in a city or a congested or a within a highly populated place, Since, you need to do a lots of gear transitions over a short distance.

One more thing to be noted as far as the engine oil and its relation to mileage is concerned to be noted down. As long as the engine has the engine oil for its functionality the engine oil quality will goes down with respect to time and distance covered. This is to be noted.

Some other parameters which may influences or promotes the mileage in bike are:

1. Riding Style (Riding at a consistent speed)
2. Engine Oil Quality
3. Smooth Transmission (Chains are cleaned and lubricated well)
4. Lesser the Power (Less CC) of the vehicle more the mileage.
5. Ensuring the Tyre pressure are at recommended level (Filling Nitrogen Gas
   is recommended)
6. Cleaned Air Filter and Carburetor
7. Climate or Environmental temperature (To some extent)

The higher the quality of the engine oil, higher the mileage. In other words, if engine oil seems to be good over a period of time then it will enhance your mileage.

Hope this information helps. And the answer is relevant to the question requested to some extent.

Thank You!!

Comment: Welcome - your post currently needs a lot of work. Your 1st section doesn't answer the question. The 2nd and final sections are not helpful - use the specific guidance in the manual, not rule of thumb. The distances you give here would be very wrong for some vehicles. eg my last two cars, from the same manufacturer: one had oil change recommended every 12000 miles, the other was every 7500 miles. Please read our [about] and [answer] pages for guidance on posting here.

Comment: @Rory Alsop: Thank you for letting me know. Will check and make corrections. Will be updated soon.